# Add to cart button not working on product pages

Tags: addtocart, shopping-cart, magento-1.6

Recently I started to make some changes on my Magento website, and now the add to cart button isn't working on the product view page. I have tried things such as changing the code in `view.phtml` and adding `$.noConflict()`, but it still doesn't work.

The error code found in the chrome element inspector:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined at
>   HTMLButtonElement.onclick.

I also found this error in the Chrome inspector:

> GET [Product Link] 500 (Internal server error)

My code in view.phtml:

```
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;
        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        var msgHtml;
        var productImg = jQuery('.main-thumbnail').html();
        var windowOver = jQuery('#addedoverlay');
        var windowBox = jQuery('#added');
        var titleForBox = jQuery('#productname').text();
        if (!url) {
            url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
        }
        url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
        data += '&isAjax=1';
        windowOver.show();
        windowBox.show().css({
         backgroundImage: "url('<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/loading.gif')?>')"
        });
        try {
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data : data,
                error : function(data) {
                    windowBox.css({
                          backgroundImage: 'none'
                    }).html('<?php echo $this->__('Error') ?>');
                    windowOver.one('click',function(){
                        hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver);
                    });

                    jQuery('#hidewindow').click(function(){
                        hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver);
                    });
                },
                success : function(data) {

                    if(data.status == 'SUCCESS'){
                        if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
                            jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                        }
                        if(jQuery('.header .block-cart-header')){
                            jQuery('.header .block-cart-header').replaceWith(data.topcart);
                        }
                        msgHtml = '<div class="image-popup">' + productImg + '</div><em>' + titleForBox + '</em> <?php echo $this->__('was successfully added to your shopping cart.') ?><div style="clear:both;"></div><a id="hidewindow" class="button" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?></a>&nbsp;<a class="button" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo $this->__('View cart & checkout') ?></a>';
                    }else{
                        msgHtml = '<p class="error-msg" style="margin-bottom:15px;">' + data.message + '</p><button class="button" id="hidewindow"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue shopping') ?></span></span></button>&nbsp;<button class="button" onclick="window.location=\'<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>;\'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('View cart & checkout') ?></span></span></button>';
                    }

                    windowBox.css({
                          backgroundImage: 'none'
                    }).html(msgHtml);
                    windowOver.one('click',function(){
                        hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver);
                    });

                    jQuery('#hidewindow').click(function(){
                        hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver);
                    });



                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
        }
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    function hidewindow(windowBox,windowOver){
        windowOver.fadeOut(400);
        windowBox.fadeOut(400).html('');
    }

//]]>
```

I was hoping someone could help me with this problem, because I haven't found a way to solve this.
My magento theme is Decostore

If you want me to include more code from my magento website, feel free to ask.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out!
It turned out to be error in `app/design/frontend/decostore/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml`.
There was an extra `<?php endif; ?>` there, but no `<?php if; ?>` which caused an Internal server error on getting the page url. That's why the `productAddToCartForm` didn't have a value.
Everything works as intended now and no errors appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you try to refresh your cache (System -> Cache Management -> Flush Magento Cache)?
2. Could you try to disable flat tables for products? It can be done via updating `System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Category` and Use Flat Catalog Product to No.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it doesnt work. I have refreshed the cache and `Flat Catalog Category` and `Flat Catalog Product` Were set to no already